# Listview inside listview is not scrolling

Tags: android

I am using ListView inside ListView to display some data..I am getting the data properly but inner ListView is not getting scrolled..It is showing me the scrollbar but then too it is not getting scrolled..

Any help is appreciated.. I know there are many questions on this but i am not able to achieve what i want

this is first layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".activity.PendingSalesPurchaseActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="7dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="7dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/voucher_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/card"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="7dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="7dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="7dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/party"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gst_no"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="GSTIN No."
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/gst"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="TextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/l2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Email"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Phone"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/phone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Address"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/address"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/card2"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="7dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="7dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView38"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ITEMS"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView38"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="30dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:visibility="gone" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/card3"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="7dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="7dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NET AMOUNT"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/net"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

layout for adapter of first layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Ref No."
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vno"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Date"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/billdate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="Amount:"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/l2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

layout for adapter for inner listview inside adapter

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"

            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qty"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rate"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The question is too broad. Please show us what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin i edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter != null) {

            int numberOfItems = listAdapter.getCount();

            // Get total height of all items.
            int totalItemsHeight = 0;
            for (int itemPos = 0; itemPos < numberOfItems; itemPos++) {
                View item = listAdapter.getView(itemPos, null, listView);
                float px = 500 * (listView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
                item.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) px, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                totalItemsHeight += item.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            // Get total height of all item dividers.
            int totalDividersHeight = listView.getDividerHeight() *
                    (numberOfItems - 1);
            // Get padding
            int totalPadding = listView.getPaddingTop() + listView.getPaddingBottom();

            // Set list height.
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalItemsHeight + totalDividersHeight + totalPadding;
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Android documentation - `Listview`: `ListView` is a view group that displays a list of scrollable items

You do not really want to scroll that inner list view, you want to scroll the outer listview. However I asume that the inner listview may vary on the amount of elements it contains.

Instead of the inner list view you could use a

`linear layout`, see this tutorial or look at `Adding content to a linear layout dynamically`?

table layout For the `linear layout` (some sample code):

```
// access your linear layout
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
// load the xml structure of your row
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row);
// now fill the row as you would do with listview
//e.g. (TextView) child.findViewById(...
...
// and than add it
layout.addView(child);
```

You should save the linear layout in a view holder (see View Holder pattern). I think the `removeAllViews()` is only necessary when the current row has lesser inner rows than the reused one, so I would also save the number of rows in the view holder.

If the maximum number of inner rows is not to high you could also think about caching them in the view holder to avoid the inflate and `findByViewId` (lets say in an ArrayList).